# file maintenance script last 3 by modified time

Tags: bash, shell

Need to maintain only last 3 files by modified time in a location in filesystem

Would a simple cron on  find  -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;  suffice

are there any other best practices that can be added to make this a robust solution

Thanks and appeciate pointers

Comment: if they are log files then I suggest using the [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) utility.

Comment: last three files and giving `+3` as parameter to `-mtime` ! If your file is generated one per 24 hours then this would do. as your `find` says: delete anything which is modified more than `3*24 hours` ago

Comment: yes i guess i meant delete anything modified +3 days and yes one file /day is written